# Calculation of internal resistance of battery using potentiometer

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, batteries

In this circuit diagram current $i_{2}$ (passing through the lower circuit) is 0.
Does this mean that the potential difference between c and b is zero? But then why is current flowing through the resistive wire acb? If the potential drop is 0 wouldn't the entire circuit itself break?
(Note: I have just started reading about current electricity so I'm sorry if this question is elementary.)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this mean that the potential difference between c and b is zero?

No.

If the potential difference (voltage) between c and b were zero, then the current $i_1$ would have to be zero since the potential between c and b is the same as the voltage across $R$ (assumes ideal zero resistance galvanometer). The diagram clearly states that $i_{1}\ne 0$.

> But then why is current flowing through the resistive wire acb?

Current is flowing through the resistive wire acb because the voltage across acb is fixed at $E_1$ (shown as an ideal voltage source). The current $i$ is then equal to $E_{1}/R_{ab}$.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So then the current stops flowing through the lower loop because the emf of the battery is equal to the potential of the current?

Comment: If by "potential of the current" you mean the potential difference between c and b then yes, that potential difference will equal the emf of the battery when the current read by the galvanometer is zero.

Comment: Here are two links you may find helpful: http://classes.oc.edu/PhysicsLab/POTENTIO.htm

http://amrita.olabs.edu.in/?brch=6&cnt=1&sim=147&sub=1

Comment: They were helpful thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Potentiometer is basically used to determine the emf of an unknown cell, an unknown resistance or the internal resistance of a cell.

When we connect the external cell (here E), we connect it to the main circuit with the help of a tap key and galvanometer. Now even if a small amount of current is flowing through the Galvanometer, it will show some deflection.

Now in the given circuit current is not flowing in the upper loop, this implies that the potential difference between point c & the corner where you have mentioned i2=0 is zero and not points c & b.

As no current flows the potential drop across the two segments (bc) and (the lower with E and r) is equal

Comment: But why is the current 0? That's the only thing I don't understand.  If the current is zero I understand how to find the emf and internal resistance.

Comment: Because the absolute potentials at the points are same